# Drupal newsletter subscription at registration

Tags: php, drupal, subscription, newsletter

i have a drupal site with many users.

I want to add newsletter checkbox in the registration form that allows users to get subscribed to news letters automatically while registration.

Comment: Hi, you may find better support for non programming drupal questions on the drupal answers stack exchange site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the simplenews module, it allows just this and manages, sending and un subscriptions.

edit

go to 
admin/settings/simplenews

On the page there is a group box "User registration page options" open that and you can choose which newsletters to show on the registration form.

note this may only be in the .2 version of the module.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i have tried that module, but i want the subscriptions in the registration process..